# Puppeteer: Page utilizing WebGL that takes 70 seconds to finish on Ubuntu server while it takes 1 second on Windows desktop

Tags: ubuntu, webgl, puppeteer

When navigating to https://ui.vision/demo/templatematching.js/ from my Windows desktop with GPU, it takes less than a second to load. However, when I run the same script on on an ubuntu 18.04 server without a gpu, it takes 70 seconds or more to finish.

This is my script you can run to verify:

```
const chromium = require('chrome-aws-lambda');
var Xvfb = require('@cypress/xvfb');
var xvfb = new Xvfb({});
  xvfb.start(function(err, xvfbProcess) {
    console.log('started xvfb')
  });

(async () => {

    let result = null;
    let browser = null;

    try {
            browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
                    args: chromium.args,
                    defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
                    executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
                    headless: true,
                    args: ['--use-gl=desktop', '--disable-gpu']
            });

            let page = await browser.newPage();
                const webgl = await page.evaluate(() => {
                const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
                const expGl = canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');

                return {
                          gl: gl && gl instanceof WebGLRenderingContext,
                          expGl: expGl && expGl instanceof WebGLRenderingContext,
                        };
            });

            console.log('WebGL Support:', webgl);
            await page.goto("https://ui.vision/demo/templatematching.js/",
                             {"waitUntil" : "networkidle0", "timeout": 0});
            title = await page.title();
            console.log(title);
            await delay(100);
            await page.screenshot({path: '../img/now.png'});

    } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            return error;
    } finally {
            if (browser !== null) {
                    await browser.close();
            }
            console.log("close")
    }

})();


async function delay(time) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve) {
       setTimeout(resolve, time)
   });
}
```

Is there any way to speed this up on my Ubuntu server significantly so that it loads as quickly as my desktop? On my 18.04 Ubuntu server with 1GB of RAM it consumes 99% of CPU with 15% of memory for a good minute before finally taking the snapshot.

Comment: Does the page animate? I had an issue where I used `networkidle2` on my mac. If the page had a requestAnimationFrame loop it **never** exited (well I had the timeout set to 25 seconds). I solved it by injecting a rAF handler that runs using setTimeout and much less often. See [this](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5306#issuecomment-573617612) Just in case that's out of date here's [the current code](https://github.com/greggman/check-all-the-errors/blob/master/lib/inject.js)

Comment: the page does not animate but it draws on the canvas i think

Comment: 0.7 on Windows 10 with 2080ti (13.5Tflops), 3.3 on Windows server 2019 with GTX470 (1Tflops). I think you should not run this on your ubuntu server without any GPU.

Comment: did you build your own server with GPU? is there any VPS hosting that can provide a mid-tier graphic card?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?